# Ivy gen addon creates round shapes

Tags: add-on, bezier-curves, workflow

I was working on a scene but needed some quick realistic ivy. I heard good things about the ivy gen add-on so I tried it. I followed some tutorials but whenever I change the length or any settings of the ivy it turns into large spheres and round shapes.

[image: before i change the settings]

[image: After changing settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting Ivy Branch size to 0.001